# Extract spot color from PDF to separate file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Is it possible to extract from PDF selected (or all) spot color to separate file (also PDF - i need to preserve vector lines)? It would be best if separation will produce file with separated spot and second file with everything except this spot.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly 'possible', though not currently by using Ghostscript. You could use the devices which currently exist to filter images, text and linework to instead check the colour space of the object and use some other criteria (i.e. 'spot colour') to decide whether to pass a marking operation on to the output device. You would need to look at the ghostpdl/devices/gdevoflt.c file, and investigate the colour representation in Ghostscript.

Ghostscript's pdfwrite device can't produce two PDF files from the same input (and I suspect most PDF consumers/editors won't be able to either), you would have to run the file twice. The reason is that the graphics state would need to be maintained separately from the colour and maintained in synch between the output files.

You need to think about a few things; what exactly do you mean by 'spot colour' ? objects specified in a /Separation colour space ? What about DeviceN ? What about colourants such as /None or /All ?

Comment: Ok, I see that GS pdfwrite can't produce two files. 
So let's focus on basic problem: I can use tiffsep device to obtain each color in separate tiff files. And I am searching how to get similar action but obtaining only selected color in pdf file (identified as pdf:SpotColor-0: HereIsColorName).

Comment: What you are describing  (identified as pdf:SpotColor-0: HereIsColorName) isn't what's in a PDF file, I assume its what you are retrieving from 'somewhere else'. You need to think about the actual content of a PDF file when you ask this kind of question.

Comment: As I said inmy answer, Ghostscript won't do what you want 'as is'. You can take the filtering devices in gdevoflt.c and modify them though. Currently those devices remove all the instances of one kind of object (text, linework or image) and pass on the others. If you altered one so that it removed operations which aren't 'in a spot colour' (defined any way you want) and passed on the ones which are, and then used the pdfwrite device as the outptu device, you woudl get all the spot operations in the output. Flip the device the other way to get the opposite file. This will require C coding.